# Миниатюра при просмотре статьи в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, css

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы в Wordpress не показывалась миниатюра, когда переходишь к просмотру полной статьи?

Comment: Изменить вывод?!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! Возможно, что я не понял вопрос, но всё-таки постараюсь помочь.
Перейдите в админке **Параметры -> Чтение**.
*Для каждой статьи в ленте отображать:* Полный текст или Анонс (выбираете то, что вам нужно).

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, нужно удалить кусок кода в файле single.php,который находиться в папке темы, который отвечает за вывод миниатюры в постах. Посмотреть какой именно код нужно удалить поможет [дополнение FireBug](http://samodelkin.kz/dopolnenie-firefox-dlya-kazhdogo-vebmastera-firebug.html) для Мозилы.